# Running an alias in a bash script gives me `<arguments>: command not found`

Tags: bash, alias

I have a script with an alias `_test`. It works fine, but before printing the output, it does `<arguments>: command not found`. For example, `_test -h` gives `line 49: -h: command not found`

This is a minimal example:

```
alias _test='
echo Hi
'
shopt -s expand_aliases

_test -h
```

EDIT: For those asking about using functions, I did in fact, used to have a function instead -- but it started to cause recursion problems. I just wanted something similar to a macro -- something that acts as if the text was inserted into the script.

EDIT 2: I just realized why I kept having recursion with my function/alias. I fixed it, and I switched back to a function, but this question may help someone else.

Comment: @thatotherguy Edited.

Comment: Arguments to aliases are always simply appended after the alias text, not provided as `$1, $2` etc as they would in a function. The general rule of thumb with aliases is that if you have to ask, you should be using a function instead.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the newlines. As written, `_test -h` expands to this, with a blank line above and below the echo:

```
echo Hi
-h
```

Make it a one-line alias:

```
alias _test='echo Hi'
```

---

In general, though, **avoid aliases**. They're really intended for convenience in interactive shells. In a script—or heck, even in interactive shells—it's better to **use functions instead**. For example:

```
_test() {
    echo Hi "$@"
}
```

> For those asking about using functions, I did in fact, used to have a function instead -- but it started to cause recursion problems. I just wanted something similar to a macro -- something that acts as if the text was inserted into the script.

Were you trying to wrap an existing command, like this?

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto -F'
```

If so you can use `command` to prevent a function calling itself recursively. The equivalent function would be:

```
ls() {
    command ls --color=auto -F "$@"
}
```

`command ls` calls the `ls` command rather than the `ls` function we've just defined so we don't get stuck in an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: No, it was something else -- I'll post a new question because the alias is displaying the same recursive behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kugelman's answer, I was able to solve it with

```
alias _test='
echo Hi
true'
shopt -s expand_aliases

_test -h
```